# suitable output of hexdump in bash to be input of hex2bin function in php

Tags: php, bash, centos, hexdump

A simple case , what's the suitable output for [hexdump](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_hexdump.htm) in bash (what needed options) to make it proper to be an input for [hex2bin](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hex2bin.php) function in php !  
P.S : I'm using it for streaming a certificate (made by OpenSSL command) via web service . 
I've updated PHP to 5.4.0 & I'm using CentOS 6

Answer (score 0):

`hexdump -e '1/1 "%02x"'` does the trick.

P.S. To avoid extra dependencies on hexdump binary you might want to consider using php for that and to write a short loop reading from stdin and writing out via bin2hex().

Comment: output of this command didn't go with hex2bin . no error or warning and  no output either .
I'm forced to make this sequence in calling to separate bash code which deals with files on the server from web service from PHP interface which just deal with WS response .

Answer (score 0):

solution is to remove spaces of the output of bash 
in bash :

```
res=`xxd -p $exportedkey`
echo "${res//[[:space:]]/}"
```

in php :

```
$hex = hex2bin($result);
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=hex.pfx");
header('Content-Length: '.  strlen($hex));
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');

echo $hex;
exit();
```

hope this helps others who have same problem .